# MarkLogic: Path fields with namespaces

Tags: field, marklogic

My documents have a namespace and I want to create a path field.
How do I specify the namespace while creating a path field ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Database section in the Admin ui has a page called `Path Namespaces` which can be found right next to `Path Range Indexes`. You can define your prefixes there. See also this section in the Admin guide:

[Defining Namespace Prefixes Used in Path Range Indexes and Fields](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/range_index#id_47785)

Alternatively, you can define namespaces at [Group](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/namespaces#id_43324) or [App Server](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/namespaces#id_97160) level.

HTH!